# Prerender with local test server

Tags: nginx, localhost, prerender

I would like to use Prerender on my local development servers for testing. The app server for Flask(the website backend) is running on localhost:5000 and now I have already set up a Prerender server on localhost:3000.
On the GitHub page for Prerender, it says that in order to use Prerender as local service I need to

```
export PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL=<your local url>
```

and also for my nginx configuration file

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root   /path/to/your/root;
    index  index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location @prerender {
        #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {

            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            rewrite .* /index.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1.What does

```
export PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL=<your local url>
```

do? And what should I set the "your local url" to? Should it be the url of the app server for the website (which is localhost:5000) or should it be the url of the Prerender server (which is localhost:3000).

2.I change my nginx.conf to include:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost:5000;

    root   /path/to/my/root;
    index  index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location @prerender {
        #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {

            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            set $prerender "localhost:3000";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            rewrite .* /index.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

and it doesn't seem to work. When I access localhost (localhost:80) it says 404 not found. Seems it is not even routing traffic to localhost:5000 correctly.

Any ideas as to what I have done wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the nginx configuration, you don't need to use `PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL`. It won't do anything in your case.

Changing `service.prerender.io` to `localhost:3000` like you did in your nginx config is the correct way to point at your local Prerender server.

Although, you just don't have nginx set up correctly. You will probably have to change the rewrite to index.html into a proxy_pass to localhost:5000. That should get `localhost:80` to work and then you would access the prerendered page at `localhost:80/?_escaped_fragment_=`

Comment: One note about using  $scheme. If you are behind a loadbalancer  such as in AWS, your https traffic would be sent to your nginx as http and the $scheme will try render the site in prerender as http  site rather than https. In this case, you take care to use: rewrite .* /https://$host$request_uri? break;